# jQuery autocomplete: How to complete multiple fields when entering data into one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

For my site I need the registering users to enter their zipcode and city, and entering a city should be enough for the page to auto-complete the zipcode.

Let's say I have both fields:

```
<input id="city" name="city_field" type="text">
<input id="zip" name="zip_field" type="text">
```

To auto-complete the city, I have this code, which works perfectly fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = ['New York', '...']; //I keep the entire list here
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#city").autocomplete({
            source: data
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, how do I auto-complete the zipcode right when the city is entered?

***(I keep all of the data in variables, so there is no need to connect to database)***

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [event-select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) thats available in autocomplete.

Comment: Since I'm new to jQuery, can you please give a snippet code so that I know what to do exactly. I'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Id suggest you to actually try and play around with it instead of asking us for snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = ['New York', '...']; //I keep the entire list here
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("input#city").val(ui.item.value);
            $("input#zip").val(foo(ui.item.value)); // TODO Map to zip
            return false;
        },
    });
});
</script>
```